# Bootstrap dropdown issue with modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have bootstrap dropdown when ever i am selecting a value from the dropdown it populates a modal window but when i click on "X"  to close the modal window, then selecting the same option again from the dropdown the model pop-up is not getting populated.

```js
$("#selectbox").on("change", function() {
       var sOptionVal = $(this).val();
       if (/modal/i.test(sOptionVal)) {
         var $selectedOption = $(sOptionVal);
         $selectedOption.modal('show');
       }
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select class="form-control" id="selectbox">
      <option value="#">
        Find: App Support
      </option>
    
      <option value="#myModal1">
        Apple Pear Company
      </option>
    
      <option value="#myModal2">
        Cold Brewing Company
      </option>
    
      <option value="#myModal3">
        Jokers Wild Inc.
      </option>
    </select>
    
    
    <div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Apple Pear Company</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body info">
            <p>Lorem lipsum
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer addHEIGHT">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Cold Brewing Company</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body info">
            <p>Lorem lipsum</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="myModal3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Jokers Wild Inc.</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body info">
            <p>Lorem Lipsum</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here I am attaching the jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/u20hujev/

Comment: If you select same option which is currently selected then no event is triggered. You need to select another option.

Comment: @TechBreak there is a other solution, [take a look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/wLWMc/)

Comment: @RickBronger the behavior is incorrect. It is fired on select click. Even i dont click on option and just click outside of select.

Comment: @Bhairav I saw your comments on other answers as well. For a dropdown `change` event to trigger you need to change the value of the dropdown, even if you choose the same value again the change is not triggered. Also you say that not to use `blur` and not to `reset` the dropdown. If you can tell me the purpose of this module may be we can think of different approach

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**.
When Bootstrap modal close then selected option will remove and again append an option. You can use this trick.

Hope helps you.

```js
$("#selectbox").on("change", function() {
  var sOptionVal = $(this).val();
  if (/modal/i.test(sOptionVal)) {
    var $selectedOption = $(sOptionVal);
    $selectedOption.modal('show');
 }
});

$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
 var getValueOnClose = $("#selectbox :selected").text();
 $("#selectbox :selected").remove();
 $("#selectbox :selected").text(getValueOnClose);
 $("#selectbox").append('<option value="#'+this.id+'">'+getValueOnClose+'</option>');
 $("#selectbox option:first").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br><br>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
     <select class="form-control" id="selectbox" value="10">
      <option value="#" hidden></option>
     <option value="#" selected="selected">Find: App Support</option>
     <option value="#myModal1">
       Apple Pear Company
     </option>
     <option value="#myModal2">
       Cold Brewing Company
     </option>
     <option value="#myModal3">
       Jokers Wild Inc.
     </option>
   </select>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Apple Pear Company</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body info">
        <p>Lorem lipsum
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer addHEIGHT">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Cold Brewing Company</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body info">
        <p>Lorem lipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Jokers Wild Inc.</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body info">
        <p>Lorem Lipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use change and blur both event, so if option is selected same as previous then on blur it will show modal

```
$("#selectbox").on("change blur", function() {
   var sOptionVal = $(this).val();
   if (/modal/i.test(sOptionVal)) {
     var $selectedOption = $(sOptionVal);
     $selectedOption.modal('show');
   }
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u20hujev/13/

Comment: I don't want use any blur event and also we cant reset the value to first option.

Comment: @Sam **Blur** event is not a right solution for this so we can use **:selected**  to pick text and set for render like selected.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to reset the select when you click `x`. This is because if you try to click on same `option` which is currently `selected` then it will not trigger any event.

This will make sure when you re-select any option it will show you up the modal.

```
$("#selectbox").on("change", function() {
   var sOptionVal = $(this).val();
   if (/modal/i.test(sOptionVal)) {
     var $selectedOption = $(sOptionVal);
     $selectedOption.modal('show');
   }
 });

 $("button.close").click(function(){
   $("select#selectbox").val($("select#selectbox option:first").val());
 });
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qaeed/u20hujev/16/

Comment: ,Thanks for the response ,but I dont want to reset the select option.